# How to properly make a Raw SQL in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am into a Rails Console session trying to run a Raw SQL query. If I use Active Record like this, this is the result:

```
irb(main):006:0> count = Sf::Program.count
  Sf::Program Count (132.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "salesforce"."program__c"
=> 54348
```

If I try to run this same query, but with ActiveRecord

```
irb(main):007:0> sql =  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM salesforce.program__c'
=> "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM salesforce.program__c"
irb(main):008:0> sql =  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "salesforce"."program__c"'
=> "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \"salesforce\".\"program__c\""
irb(main):009:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
```

IM getting an error

```
/Volumes/Laje/fmaymone/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:768:in `exec_params': ERROR:  relation "salesforce.program__c" does not exist (PG::UndefinedTable)                               
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "salesforce"."program__c"
```

What IM doing wrong here???

Comment: Your SQL code is wrong. You should reference the table after the FROM clause, you're using the table column (`salesforce.program__c`). Try just `select count(*) from salesforce` (or `select count(program__c) from salesforce`, don't know really what's your intent).

Comment: Salesforce is the schema and program__c the table

Comment: Both ways work for me. Use psql to get a cleaner error.